# multivariate regression

Tags: r, model, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have two dependents that both depent on two variables AND on each other, can this be modelled in R (must be!) but I can't figure out how, anyone a hint?

In clear terms:

I want to model my data with the following model:

```
Y1=X1*coef1+X2*coef2
Y2=X1*coef2+X2*coef3
```

Note: coef2 appears in both lines
Xi, Yi is input and output data respectively

I got this far:

```
lm(Y1~X1+X2,mydata)
```

now how do I add the second line of the model including the cross dependency?

Your help is greatly appreciated!
Cheers, Bastiaan

Comment: This question is probably suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ You may also want to change the title as multivariate regression does not seem to be what you want: this would simply be `lm(cbind(Y1, Y2) ~ X1 + X2, mydata)` which is equivalent to doing both regressions separately without constraining two weights to be equal. You may have to look into structural equation modeling. Packages `sem`, `lavaan`, and `OpenMx` will get you further. You can also look into http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-sems.pdf

Comment: When you posed this problem in r-help it turned out that Y1 and Y2 were x and y projections of a distance that depended on the angle. It was never clarified how many measurements there were, what sort of counts there were per unit under analysis, or whether the the analyst would need to control for distance from the center. If you would include more context you might get a better answer.

Comment: Checking back only 2 years later. I thought I had only posted in R-Help. Anyway, my solution was to get away from R, or rather stay in R without using the build in functions. Kind of disappointing, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
# sample data - true coefs are 2, 3, 4
set.seed(123)
n <- 35
DF <- data.frame(X1 = 1, X2 = 1:n, X3 = (1:n)^2)
DF <- transform(DF, Y1 = X1 * 2 + X2 * 3 + rnorm(n), 
          Y2 = X1 * 3 + X2 * 4 + rnorm(n))

# construct data frame for required model
DF2 <- with(DF, data.frame(y = c(Y1, Y2), 
x1 = c(X1, 0*X1),
x2 = c(X2, X1),
x3 = c(0*X2, X2)))

lm(y ~. - 1, DF2)
```

We see it does, indeed, recover the true coefs of 2, 3, 4:

```
> lm(y ~. - 1, DF2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ . - 1, data = DF2)

Coefficients:
   x1     x2     x3  
2.084  2.997  4.007
```